# Как отобрать срез строк после фильтрования строк фрейма?

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
data = {'фрукт': ['арбуз','арбуз','арбуз','арбуз','груша', 'груша', 'груша', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'абрикос', 'абрикос', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия','сша', np.nan, 'россия', np.nan, np.nan,'канада', 'франция', 'португалия', 'испания', np.nan, np.nan, 'перу'],
'вид_фр': ['1','2','3','10', '5', '7', '5', '6', '10', '5', '5', '7', '7']
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'вид_фр'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После применения фильтра для вывода строк с грушами, получаю такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить срез (выделен также красным в первом скриншоте) со второй строки, содержащей грушу до значения следующего за послдней строкой, которая содержит грушу.

Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно и "в лоб" решить, просто добавив к индексам среза 1:

```
dates.loc[dates.loc[dates.фрукт == 'груша'].index + 1]
```

Или тоже самое с помощью "сдвига" булевой маски среза на 1:

```
dates.loc[(dates.фрукт == 'груша').shift(fill_value=False)]
```

Вывод:

```
    фрукт   страна      вид_фр
5   груша   NaN         7
6   груша   канада      5
7   груша   франция     6
8   вишня   португалия  10
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно применить к groupby фрейму? Например, если есть даты поставок фруктов, и я сгруппировал по дате поставки. Хочу за каждую дату поставки получить срез

Comment: @formanite Кажется, вам лучше отдельный вопрос про это задать, чтобы в этом вопросе путаницу не разводить.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1230242/255714 @CrazyElf

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
idx = dates.query('фрукт == "груша"').index
res = dates.loc[idx.min()+1:idx.max()+1]
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно применить к groupby фрейму? Например, если есть даты поставок фруктов, и я сгруппировал по дате поставки. Хочу за каждую дату поставки получить срез