# Pandas Как отобрать срез строк по группам после фильтрования строк фрейма

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','груша','арбуз','банан','груша', 'груша', 'вишня', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия','сша', np.nan, 'россия', np.nan, np.nan,'канада', 'франция', 'португалия', 'испания', np.nan, np.nan, 'перу'],
'id': ['01','01','01','011', '011', '011', '011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['январь','январь','январь','январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'март', 'март', 'апрель', 'апрель', 'апрель', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно отфильтровать срезы строк с грушей так, чтобы за каждый месяц срез начинался со второй строки, содержащей грушу, и заканчивался строкой, следующей после последней строки с грушей. Обязательное условие - группировка, а не сортировка. Задачу решаю в общем виде, т.е. предположим , что вместо месяца даны id. Поэтому сортировка уже не поможет

Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат (также на первом скриншоте выделил, что должны получить в результате):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам уже подсказали ответ на аналогичный вопрос. Ваш код где? что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @strawdog Да я сначала подумал, что тут что-то ещё придётся думать и поэтому сказал задать новый вопрос, но оказалось, что уже и правда всё есть в прошлом вопросе, вы правы.

Comment: Извините, я забыл указать, что обязательным условием является именно группировка, а не обычная сортировка по возрастанию\убыванию @strawdog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я посмотрел, ответ будет тот же самый, что и в предыдущем вашем вопросе, если данные уже отсортированы нужным образом по месяцам:

```
dates.loc[(dates.фрукт == 'груша').shift(fill_value=False)]
```

Вывод:

```
фрукт   страна  вид_фр  месяц
1   груша   сша 2   январь
2   арбуз   NaN 3   январь
5   груша   NaN 7   февраль
6   вишня   канада  5   февраль
8   вишня   португалия  10  март
11  груша   NaN 7   апрель
12  банан   перу    7   апрель
```

А если нужной сортировки нет, то нужно завести колонку с цифровыми номерами месяцев (иначе нормально не отсортируется) и предварительно сделать `dates = dates.sort_values("номер_месяца")`.

А группы тут никак не нужны, достаточно сортировки.

Comment: Извините, я забыл указать, что обязательным условием является именно группировка, а не обычная сортировка по возрастанию\убыванию. Не могли бы привести код с группировкой? Положите, что вместо месяцев указаны id

Comment: @formanite А что вы с группировкой то хотите сделать в итоге? Непонятно.

Comment: Предположим, что фрейм отсортирован, но есть еще id по каждой строке. И в январе могут встречаться различные id. По этим id я и хочу провести группировку, а далее уже получить нужный срез

Comment: Обновил условия задачи и приложил новые скриншоты и данные. Данные отсоритированы по месяцу, но нужна группировка по id (можно полагать, что id - это конкретный рейс , который доставлял фрукты)

Comment: А вы сами что-то пробовали? Мне кажется, strawdog прав и вам надо бы и самостоятельно что-то пытаться делать. У меня работа, потом может вернусь к этому вопросу.

Comment: Конечно пытался, неуспешно

Comment: @formanite Ну так и группируйте: `dates.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x)` как-то так. а затем уже применяйте решение, предложенное CrazyElf

Answer (score 0):

```
dates.groupby('id').head(1000000000).loc[(dates.фрукт == 'груша').shift(fill_value=False)]
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это рабочий ответ на ваш же вопрос? если нет, то удалите его и поместите в тело вопроса. Вообще, на какую-то ерунду похоже.

Comment: Да, это рабочий ответ. loc на groupby объекты не работает, поэтому пришлось через head костыль делать @strawdog

Comment: я вам в комментарии к ответу CrazyElf написал, как можно сделать "пустую" операцию надо группой.